# RSpec with Ruby on Rails - Wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) when testing routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd

I tried testing routes and just copied the example from the rspec-rails documentation.

```
describe "routing to profiles" do
  it "routes /profile/:username to profile#show for username" do
    expect(:get => "/profiles/jsmith").to route_to(
      :controller => "profiles",
      :action => "show",
      :username => "jsmith"
    )
  end
end
```

I got the following error when running RSpec:

```
Failures:

  1) routing to profiles routes /profile/:username to profile#show for username
     Failure/Error: expect(:get => "/profiles/jsmith").to route_to(
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
     # ./spec/routing/test_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.001 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

What's going wrong here?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It was 2.8.1, updated and the problem  was sovled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expect` takes a block. This means use curly brackets:

```
expect{ :get => "/profiles/jsmith" }.to route_to(
```

Reference: [RSpec Expectations 2.0](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/expect-change)

I don't think you need expect anyway. Code from  [Testing an RSpec controller action that can't be accessed directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227638/testing-an-rspec-controller-action-that-cant-be-accessed-directly)

```
describe "routing" do
  it "routes /auth/:provider/callback" do
    { :post => "/auth/twitter/callback" }.should route_to(
      :controller => "authentications",
      :action => "create",
      :provider => "twitter")
  end
end
```

Comment: This is only true for old versions of rspec prior to 2.11, in which  `expect{}.to` was just sugar for `lambda{}.should`. As of 2.11 `expect` can take arguments for value assertions, just as in the OP's example. See: http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax#unification_of_block_vs_value_syntaxes

Comment: My version of RSpec turned out to be the problem, since it was an older one. Having said that, the rspec-rails documentation on http://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails differs from http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/frames, so its a bit confusing...

Comment: It was my rspec version that was causing the same problem for me.  Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 0):

Your `it` block lists `/profile/:username` while your example lists `/profiles/jsmith` (note the plural on profile(s)). I'm guessing it should be `/profile/jsmith`.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the get command is `get your_action, params => your_params`.  I would try using `get :show, username => "user"` in conjunction with curly braces as B Seven suggested. You also may need to wrap your spec in a describe block such as `describe MyController do`, or possibly pass in the name of the controller as parameter