# Rspec: Test redirects in Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, integration-testing, omniauth

Following the [Railscast on Devise and OmniAuth](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised?view=asciicast) I have implemented an `OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController` which contains a single method to handle an OmniAuth callback:

```
def all
  user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
  if user.persisted?
    sign_in_and_redirect user
  else
    session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
  end
end
alias_method :facebook, :all
```

routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks", :sessions => "sessions" }
```

I would like to customise this, so I'm trying to test it using RSpec. The question is how do I test this method and the redirects?

If in the spec I put `user_omniauth_callback_path(:facebook)` it doesn't complain about the route not existing, but doesn't seem to actually call the method.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4228714/1450420) "controller tests use the four HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE), regardless of whether your controller is RESTful."  I tried `get user_...` etc. but here it does complain that the route doesn't exist.  And indeed if I do `rake routes` it shows there is no HTTP verb for this route:

```
user_omniauth_callback [BLANK] /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format) omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:facebook)
```

Can you see what I'm missing?

**EDIT**

So following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989461/runtimeerror-actioncontrollerrackdelegation-in-rspec-2-10-1-for-rails-3-1-4-a) one way of calling the method is:

```
controller.send(:all)
```

However I then run into the same error that the questioner ran into:

```
ActionController::RackDelegation#content_type delegated to @_response.content_type, but @_response is nil
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to do three things to get this accomplished.

- enter OmniAuth test environment
- create an OmniAuth test mock
- stub out your from_omniauth method to return a user

Here is a possible solution, entered in the spec itself 
(spec/feature/login_spec.rb for example) . . .

```
let(:current_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

before do
  OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
  OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new({
    provider: :facebook,
    uid:'12345',
    info: {
      name: "Joe"
    }
  })
  User.stub(:from_omniauth).and_return(current_user)
end
```

I adapted this from a google authentication, so facebook may require more fields, but those are the only ones [required by omniauth docs](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing).  You should be able to find the correct fields by looking at your database schema and finding fields that match the documentation.

In my case, the minimum was enough to pass the request phase and move onto the stubbed out method returning my user.

This example also uses [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl).

It may not be perfect, but I hope it helps.  Good luck!

-Dan

Comment: Perfect.  Helpful on many levels, not least that I was thinking about this as a controller spec rather than a feature spec.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to help!  This brought me to my knees for a day and a half.  I'm glad someone else can benefit from my frustration!  Was the syntax far off?  If so, please edit with the correct solution.  Thanks!

Comment: The syntax worked perfectly. The only change I made was pulling a bit into spec_helper.rb following [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9915796/1450420) which I found thanks to your answer.

Comment: Ahhh, interesting.  I stubbed out the method so I wouldn't need an actual result saved, but that is probably a more accurate representation.  I'm assuming by setting the env.request["omniauth.env"], you can grab a user from persistance and have no need for the stubbing, right?   Also, moving the omniauth test setup into a spec_helper is definitely more dry.  Thanks for the update!

Comment: The only change I made was pulling a bit more into spec_helper.rb.  I didn't try setting the `request.env["omniauth.auth"]` in a before block.  I was happy enough that it was dry and working so I thought it best to quit while I was ahead!

Comment: I haven't touched it in a few years, so sadly, no not adjusted.

Answer (score 3):

If you hit this and you are running **rspec 3.4** this example should work for you:

```
describe Users::OmniauthCallbacksController, type: :controller do
  let(:current_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  before do
    OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
    OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:your_oauth_provider_here] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new(
      provider: :your_oauth_provider_here,
      uid: rand(5**10),
      credentials: { token: ENV['CLIENT_ID'], secret: ENV['CLIENT_SECRET'] }
    )
    request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    allow(@controller).to receive(:env) { { 'omniauth.auth' => OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:your_oauth_provider_here] } }
    allow(User).to receive(:from_omniauth) { current_user }
  end

  describe '#your_oauth_provider_here' do
    context 'new user' do
      before { get :your_oauth_provider_here }

      it 'authenticate user' do
        expect(warden.authenticated?(:user)).to be_truthy
      end

      it 'set current_user' do
        expect(current_user).not_to be_nil
      end

      it 'redirect to root_path' do
        expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing problem for writhing `RSpec` for `OmniauthCallbacksController`, do some research on this and it working for me. Here is my codes, if anyone found necessary. Tests are for happy path and it should work for news version of `RSpec eg. 3.x`

```
   require 'spec_helper'

    describe OmniauthCallbacksController, type: :controller do
      describe "#linkedin" do
        let(:current_user) { Fabricate(:user) }

        before(:each) do
          OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
          OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:linkedin] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new({provider: :linkedin, uid: '12345', credentials: {token: 'linkedin-token', secret: 'linkedin-secret'}})
          request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]

          @controller.stub!(:env).and_return({"omniauth.auth" => OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:linkedin]})
          User.stub(:from_auth).and_return(current_user)
        end

        describe "#linkedin" do
          context "with a new linkedin user" do
            before { get :linkedin }

            it "authenticate user" do
              expect(warden.authenticated?(:user)).to be_truthy
            end

            it "set current_user" do
              expect(subject.current_user).not_to be_nil
            end

            it "redirect to root_path" do
              expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
            end
          end
        end

      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is `omniauthcontrollercallback`, that worked for me.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Users::OmniauthCallbacksController, type: :controller do
  describe "#google_oauth2" do
    before do
      request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    end

    context "with valid user" do
      let(:role) {Role.create!(name: 'candidate')}
        let(:user) {User.create!(email: 'user@example.com', password: '123456', role_id: role.id, approved: true)}
      let(:auth) do
        OmniAuth::AuthHash.new({
          provider: 'google_oauth2',
          uid: '123456',
          info: { email: user.email },
          credentials: {
            token: 'token',
            expires_at: Time.now + 1.hour,
            refresh_token: 'refresh_token'
          }
        })
      end

      before do
        request.env["omniauth.auth"] = auth
      end

      it "signs in the user and redirects to the root path" do
        expect(User).to receive(:from_omniauth).with(auth).and_return(user)
        expect(user).to receive(:persisted?).and_return(true)
        expect(user).to receive(:save!)

        get :google_oauth2
        expect(flash[:notice]).to eq(I18n.t("devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", kind: "Google"))
        expect(user.access_token).to eq(auth.credentials.token)
        expect(user.expires_at.utc.to_s).to eq(auth.credentials.expires_at.utc.to_s)
        expect(user.refresh_token).to eq(auth.credentials.refresh_token)
        expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
      end
    end

    context "with invalid user" do
      let(:auth) { OmniAuth::AuthHash.new(provider: 'google_oauth2', uid: 'invalid') }

      before do
        request.env["omniauth.auth"] = auth
      end

      it "redirects to the new user registration page" do
        expect(User).to receive(:from_omniauth).with(auth).and_return(User.new)
        expect_any_instance_of(User).to receive(:persisted?).and_return(false)

        get :google_oauth2
        expect(session["devise.google_data"]).to eq(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
        expect(response).to redirect_to(new_user_registration_url)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: I am a newbie too, I was working with rspecs and then I had to write rspec for omniauthcallback so I came to this page looking for reference and then I researched and found this helpul hence uploaded it, so that any other newbie like me get the idea to write its rspec.